# PowerShell Stopping and Starting Services with Server names masked by DNS Alias

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PowerShell that accepts a file as a parameter that contains Server-Name, Service-Name and Timeout specified in seconds and the powershell stops/starts the services based on the command. I have 10 servers where application related services are configured and I'm using Workload automation capabilities to run this code on any server with the same parameter file and powershell present on all 10 servers.

All of this works fine with server names hardcoded in the param file. We have `n+2 Infrastructure`, and I created DNS Aliases for all the 10 servers to make Active-Standby switchover little easy. Now the problem comes with stop/start script. Ex: If the script gets invoked in Server 7, all the services will be shutdown except for the ones in Server 7 and I get below error:

> Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name
>   'Application-Server7'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-Service -ComputerName app7test -Name Application-Server7
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Application-Server7:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

I just tested one-liner command using PowerShell ISE on the computer **"appnewora79"** and below are the results.

This works fine:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName appnewora79 -Name Application-Server7
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Stopped  Application-Ser... Application-Server7
```

This fails:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName app7test -Name Application-Server7
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'Application-Server7'
```

> At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-Service -ComputerName app7test -Name Application-Server7
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Application-Server7:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

Any suggestions to overcome this, please?

I tried below as well:

It all works when the server name is hardcoded. If I change it to DNS Alias name then Get-Service fails on the server where it is executing while fetching service details only related to the same server.

On the Server-1, if I run below commands, they all work fine

```
Get-Service -ComputerName servername1
Get-Service -ComputerName servername2
Get-Service -ComputerName servername3
```

If I update the above command with server dns alias and execute them on Server-1, then only the first command fails, i.e.. the command with the same server name masked with DNS fails, If I run the same commands on server 2, then the second one alone fails

```
Get-Service -ComputerName dnsalias1
Get-Service -ComputerName dnsalias2
Get-Service -ComputerName dnsalias3
```

I tried, `test-connection` with DNS alias names and they go thru fine. Tried `Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_service` with computer name masked as DNS alias and it goes thru fine. I'm lost as to what could be the issue.

Below is the error message with Get-Service alone:

> Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'dnsalias1'. This operation might require other privileges.
>   At line:5 char:1
>   + Get-Service -ComputerName dnsalias1
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

Comment: I just tried test-connection with the same experiment and it is not resulting in any issues, so only while fetching services???

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of different way to resolve this as per suggestion received in PowerShell Google+ forum.

I used `Resolve-DnsName` to get hold of `IP4Address` of the server and then passed it for stopping and starting windows services and this works.